# Is a Research paper possible for proposing of a Methodology?

Tags: publications, research-process, journals

So I have been carrying out this research project related to Machine Learning and computer networks and have been writing research paper along side my work.
Now that I have reached Results and conclusion part of the paper, I come to realize that my results are not really based on numbers and values but rather it is an emphasis on a Methodology.
The Methodology is, "how **data** generated from any tool can be used to add **functionality**  in the tool given if a person is able to drive an outcome from that data".

So is a journal publication possible for a proposing of a methodology?

Comment: I think the crucial angle is whether the methodology is demonstrably useful. If you can show that it works well in specific cases, then yes.

Comment: To demonstrate it I have my own work in which it fits in perfectly. Its basically a network traffic classification engine based on ML.

Answer (score 1):

> is a journal publication possible for...a methodology?

**Yes**, assuming the ability to add functionality to a tool - from data generated by the tool - is useful to others, and assuming outcomes can be (relatively easily) manually derived from the aforementioned data. Added functionality is presumably useful, so the former assumption can be dropped. (Some justification should be added to the paper.) As to whether outcomes can be relatively easily derived, that isn't obvious and requires justification. If you can justify, then the latter assumption can be dropped too, giving-way to my answer to the above question: Yes.